# technologies of facebook

Tags: facebook

everyone, I have some question about facebook, does somebody know how was initially created facebook, I mean what basic technologies were used? for example if I want to create "my facebook" what will I need for this? I'll be also very grateful for any link about this info, thanks in advance

Comment: This is not [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/faq/), possibly it's more of a [programming-discussion](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/), or simply speculation.

Comment: it is not speculation!!!

Comment: Have you not seen the movie "The Social Network"?!  I'm with David Thomas, if this belongs anywhere, it is on http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: unless the Facebook developers are users of Stackoverflow (I see no reason why they wouldn't be) *and* are *able to answer* factually, this question has to be speculative. It could, though, be a discussion question, in which case it should be on [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/), not here.

Comment: to know which languages and technologies to use to create new application it is part of the programming, am I wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should read the [Facebook Factsheet](https://www.facebook.com/press/info.php?factsheet).

Site was originally built on [PHP](http://php.net/) and MySQL (and still uses a combination thereof to this day; albeit, much more complex combinations of architecturally). To build your own Facebook though, you don't necessarily need to use PHP. There are lots of great web frameworks you could try like [Rails](http://rubyonrails.org/), [Django](http://www.djangoproject.com/), et al.

Answer (score 2):

Facebook I believe is based on PHP, mySQL and Apache. Here you can see some of the open technologies and tools they use.

http://developers.facebook.com/opensource/

And if you are planning on making your own facebook, or something similar, you might want to give a brief look to diaspora. It is an open source social network build with Ruby on Rails.

https://joindiaspora.com/

https://github.com/diaspora/diaspora/wiki

Good luck

Kevin.